# How come retrieving an element from a list is O(1)

Tags: arrays, list, python

Today in class, we learned that retrieving an element from a list is O(1) in python. Why is this the case? Suppose I have a list of 4 items, i.e:

```
li=["perry", 1, 23.5, "s"]
```

These items have different sizes in memory. And so it is not possible to take the memory location of `li[0]`, and add 3 times the size of each element to get the memory location of `li[3]`. So how does the interpreter know where `li[3]` is without having to traverse the list in search of it?